# Rename add-ons as they appear in the N-Panel menu?

Tags: interface, add-on

I have acquired a lot of add-ons that now clutter the N-Panel menu. Is there a way to rename some of these add-ons so, at the very least, they have shorter names? I'm comfortable editing Python scripts, if it can be safely done there?

I tried a great add-on called SIMPLE TABS by Chipp Walters that allows you to rename add-ons--and more--but the problem is that not all add-ons play nicely. For example, BlenderKit and ToOptimize Tools menus become distorted and even broken up by SIMPLE TABS, and EasyLight isn't even accessible from SIMPLE TABS.

Thankfully, some add-ons allow you to change the N-Panel menu, but that's the exception. Again, I'm tempted to edit the add-on Python scripts themselves, but I'm not sure I know enough to do it without adverse consequences. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.01, Windows 11.

Comment: To do this in python, you need to edit the file with the panel class for the addon and find the `bl_category` and `bl_label` fields and modify them appropriately.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thanks! I tried this on "ToOptimize Tools", changing the name to "ToOpt." (There were a bunch of *.py files so I used a multi-file search & replace tool; there was no "bl_label" entry to be found.) It seems to have worked. Much appreciated!